# Unable to find correct tire size

Tags: tire, rims

Recently, I had a problem with the back rim (the axis) and the guy who repaired just replaced the rim.

After few weeks I tried to repair a flat tire, but I found myself unable to remove the tire to change the tube. After two or three hours of fight I found out that I had damaged the tube and the tire, and I decided to just tear the tire apart. Even doing that was difficult.

So after that, I tried with 32-622, 35-622 and 37-622 tires and none of them fit. Impossible. Not even the first bead of the tire, which is supposed to be easy.

Then I decided to measure both rims (the one that wasn't replaced and the affected one), and they seem to have the same diameter as well as the same width. The only matter in which they differ is the well depth. The "good" one has about 12mm of depth, while the one I can't mount has like 8mm.

Can anybody please suggest which tire sizes should I buy?
[image: This is the rim that I can't mount. 8mm deep well]
[image: Both rims next to each other.]

Comment: Are you using proper tire levers try to mount the tire? Looks like you've done a little damage to the rim you are holding in your hand in the bottom picture.  Also, are you sure it's not a 27 inch wheel? The difference is in diameter would only be about 8mm, which might be hard to notice when using a measuring tape, but would make a noticeable difference when trying to mount tires.

Comment: Hi Kibbee, thanks for your comment. I measured carefully both rims again. From edge to edge, there is maximum 1mm of difference. And yes, you're right, unfortunately I damaged the rim when trying to remove the old tire. I'll try to sleek those bits.
And about the levers, well, as far as I knew they should not be necessary when trying to put the first bead.

Comment: What size of tires were mounted on the tires before?

Comment: Batman: 35-622. But I believe that was not its size. It was almost impossible to take it out.

Comment: So. I measured both rims again, but this time the circumference of the bed.  The fitting rim seems to be 1 inch (~2.5cm) shorter. Maybe I need a 630 tire.

Comment: Take a look at [Sheldon Brown's excellent site](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#dishonest).  For an XX-622 tire to fit, the "bead seat diameter" shown in the diagram should be 622 mm.  Also, use only *plastic* "tire irons" when installing/removing a bike tire (or, better still, use a [Quik Stik](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/how-to-replace-a-tube-with-only-one-quick-stick)).

Comment: The tire size refers to the rim edge aka "bead seat" diameter. So, 630mm tires will be too large. The smaller diameter of rim bed makes it easier to mount tires. The tricks to try are first pushing the part of tire bead that is over the edge to the deepest part at rim center and if that fails, lubricating the rim with soap water. Some tires are also tighter than others, in my experience the regular Schwalbe Marathon is very loose (on the other hand, Plus is known to be hard to mount).

Comment: There are a decent amount of tire-rim combos which are hard to mount and remove. I'd be surprised if they managed to get a wrong tire on. Is this your first time changing a flat?

Comment: Hi @Batman no, I never had a problem changing a flat before. Now I am almost convinced they put a 27' inch (630) rim on the bike. I was not measuring the rims the right way, because from edge to edge both rims are almost identical (in terms of diameter), but if you take into account the rim beds, then there is a difference. I'll answer my own question as soon as I receive the tire I just ordered.

Comment: Edge to edge is the correct measurement. Rim bed depth varies between different rims of same size, the one that you have is shallower than usual.

Comment: Did they give you back your old wheel?  If so, stand them both on the ground side by side without a tire on the wheel.  If indeed one is a 27" (630mm) and the other a 700C (622mm), that 8mm difference should be noticeable to the naked eye.

Comment: Also, how many gears do you have in back? A 27" is likely going to have a freewheel, which means at most 7 gears. A 700C is likely going to have a cassette, which means upwards of 11 gears.

Comment: @Kennah, unfortunately I did not get the old wheel. I have to compare it to the front wheel. Edge to edge, they have the same diameter. It has freewheel and 7 gears. It's a regular city bike.
But if you're right, and they have to be compared edge to edge, why there is such difference (about 1 inch) when you compare the rim beds circumference?

Comment: If it was a 27" rim on the bike and the bike had 700c before, the brakes wouldn't line up (most likely; or they'd be adjusted in a different position). Have you looked up the bike model on the internet?

Comment: @Batman, the original wheels came with 35-622 tires. The new rim that was mounted by the mechanic doesn't have any print or mark specifying its size. I do not know if they had to adjust the brakes to the new wheel.

Comment: @mdelolmo The rim bed diameter is not standardized, it is up to manufacturer to decide it. Larger rim bed diameter makes it harder to mount tires but allows a double wall rim to be lighter or stronger for the same weight. After the tire has been mounted, the rim bed doesn't matter because the tire is held against the edges of the rim.

Comment: Is the wheel in any way marked? My old 27" Weinmann rims are marked 630mm x 16mm (I think it's 16mm).

Comment: So you were all right and the tire and the rim match (supposedly). I will just try to order an "easy-to-fit" tire, because the one I tried was just too hard. This was a truly depressing experience. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Those appear to be hooked rims,(difficult to see in the pic) which are almost all iso-622. iso-630 rims are usually straight sided rims and used only on 25-50 year old road bikes. Occasionally tires are just made with tighter bead wires. You must fully deflate the tire and break the bead seal all the way around on both sides so that the edges farthest from where you are working can slip into the center well without resistance.

You should not expect to put the first bead on fully without levers, it does happen occasionally but don't expect it. Technique is a big thing but I can't help you with that without being there.I have done some ten thousand bike tires in the shop, manufacturing tolerances are quite wide, not much you can really do about it other than practice.On the plus side, tight bead wires are less likely to let the bead pop out and cause the tube to blow out, which can happen if the tire is near max pressure in the cold morning and then parked directly in the afternoon sun. It sounds about like an M-80.

Comment: you can still buy new (perhaps they are all new-old stock though) 630 rims and tires though